# MongoDB - Database design with parent & child relationship

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, non-relational-database

In my application I have **Users** table in DB and theirs **Posts** on forum.

On every post I have a link to a user profile who wrote it.

Now, if I remove the user from DB - I want his posts to stay, but with an attribute, that “this user (author) has been deleted”.

How should I treat in this case ? User may left several thousands of posts, so if I want to remove the user, I need to select all his posts and update them one-by-one ? It may take long time.

If I mark the user like “disabled” (and don’t remove it actually) then front-end will need to send lots of additional requests for every rendered post - this is even worse.

So how should I treat with child objects if I remove the parent object ?

What do you think ? May be there is a better approach?

Comment: "If I mark the user like “disabled” (and don’t remove it actually) then front-end will need to send lots of additional requests for every rendered post" Why do you think so?

Comment: Let’s say I have 100 posts on the page from 100 unique users, then I will need to send 100 additional GET requests for user profiles, just to check if they are active

Comment: No, you just use a join query with posts and users - that's still just a single query that joins two tables...

Comment: What if it’s not a relational DB, for example Mongo DB where joining 2 tables is expensive operation ?

Comment: If it's not a relational DB than you should have mentioned it in the tags. In fact, unless it's a theoretical question or you need to support multiple databases, you should use the tag for the relevant database in your question anyway. I have done some work with MongoDB but I hardly consider myself an expert with it. I wont presume to know what advice to give you if you're not using a relational database.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes, thank you for advice it’s still good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not keep user information & posts together in same document in a collection, as you'll retrieve users details & posts separately for different purposes & also adding high no.of posts to users document is not feasible to do. So what you did by having two different collections **Users** & **Post** is correct & In **Posts** collection maintaining a single key field which relates to **User** (unique `userid` or `_id` of user document) is also correctly done.

You can avoid storing **User** relationship in **Posts** & Store all posts ids in User collection only if posts are very less in number & also this doesn't work in all of your cases. To say designing database really depends on your DB operations.

> I need to select all his posts and update them one-by-one ?

No, you don't have to select & delete one-by-one, Upon successfully deleting/disabling a user you would run a single query on **Posts** using [.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) with a filter (`userId` or `_id`) to find all docs related to particular **User** & add a new field called `isUserDeletedOrDisabled : true`, So when ever you retrieve posts for various pages of your application you would avoid retrieving those posts which has flag `isUserDeletedOrDisabled` & its `true`, In general while inserting new **Posts** docs - you don't need that flag. Upon **User** updates you'll add this field with `true` & make it `false` once user is back..

> for example Mongo DB where joining 2 tables is expensive operation ?

I don't think joining two collections using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) is much expensive, it all depends on your dataset size/index/MongoDB configuration. Have indexes on keys fields (like in **Posts** collection on **User** related field plus **isUserDeletedOrDisabled**). So for most applications if should work just fine with proper configs in place.

[Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) can help you to achieve most of the daily needs with ease, additionally you can check your query performance & improve it by looking in executionStats provided by [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html) *(or)* [$explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/index.html). For more read : [query-optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/)

Comment: This explanation is exactly what I was looking for.